# Why I am getting java.lang.AbstractMethodError errors?

Tags: java, thrift

What are the possible causes for ABstractMethodError?

Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:

```
org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.isOneway()Z
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:51)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at com.gemfire.gemstone.thrift.hbase.ThreadPoolServer$ClientConnnection.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Give us some context , what are you trying to do ? May be some version issue ! The method that you invoke or some other code invokes  is converted into an abstract method now .

Comment: I was trying out hbase thrift version. I build thrift compiler and generated thrift files. and using mvn building my project which is also downloading 0.9.0 version of apache thrift jars. this is the same I am using.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The simple answer is this:  some code is trying to call a method which is declared `abstract`.  Abstract methods have no body and cannot be executed.  Since you have provided so little information I can't really elaborate more on how this can happen since the compiler usually catches this problem - [as described here, this means the class must have changed at runtime.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html)

Comment: Yes, method is defined as abstract, but I traced through the eclipse and I see methods are implemented in child classes

Comment: Sure, but that means you have to call a specific child class implementation.  You still can't call the method itself.

Comment: I checked again , Apache thrift generated code is calling child object  specific implementation

Comment: Please double-check that. If you are still sure about it, open a JIRA ticket with a complete, reproducible test case.

Answer (score 72):

It usually means that you are using an old version of an interface implementation which is missing a new interface method. For example java.sql.Connection interface got a new getSchema method in 1.7. If you have 1.6 JDBC driver and call Connection.getSchema you will get  AbstractMethodError.

Comment: Nice, you had me at "old version of an interface"

Comment: Encountered this Exception recently. It's exactly the cause - interface incompatibly between components at runtime. One can refers to the javadoc of the exception for more details.

Answer (score 7):

From documnentation of [AbstractMethodError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html)

> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally,
>   this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run
>   time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since
>   the currently executing method was last compiled.

Answer (score 3):

if you are getting this error on a minified build using Proguard then check if the class is a POJO class and if so then exclude it from the Proguard using the below rule:

-keep class your.application.package.pojo.** {*;}

Answer (score 2):

A kind of special case of the above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17970129/6267583).

I had this error, because I was using a `spring-boot-starter-parent` (e.g. `2.1.0.RELEASE` uses spring version: `5.1.2.RELEASE`) but I **also** included a `BOM`, that also defined some spring dependencies, but in an older version (e.g. `5.0.9.RELEASE`).

So one thing to do, is check your `dependency tree` (in Eclipse e.g. you can use the Dependency Hierarchy) if you are using the same versions.

So one solution could be that you upgrade the spring dependencies in your `BOM`, another one could be that you exclude them (but depending on the amount, this could be ugly).

Comment: Thank you for "check your dependency tree"

Answer (score 1):

If you download any project zip file, after unzipping them and importing into Android Studio, you are unable to run the project because this error happened.

I got out of the problem by deleting my android studio, then download and install the new version.

I truly hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

If you you are getting this error on the implemented methods, make sure you have added your dependencies correctly as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656915/getting-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-on-implemented-method).

Answer (score 0):

As Damian quoted :

> Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only
>   occur at run time if [...]

I had the same error that was not caught by the compiler but at runtime. To solve it I only compiled again without giving the code any modification.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I imported an eclipse project into intellij ide.. I tried to import it without .iml file then my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem when I update my kotlin plugin to a new version .... the problem is that my pom file is using the older kotlin version .. I guess it might help someone if he is doing this mistake

Answer (score 0):

I am getting various of these and others infrequently on android.. I have to clean everything change som configuration rebuild change configuration again to normal somehow just the build tools don't rebuild everything they should for whatever reason (Android gradle bug obviously).