# Getting java.lang.AbstractMethodError on implemented method

Tags: java

As the title states, I get a `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` on a method that is definitively implemented by my class. The complete error message is:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: htmlexport.HTMLExport.getParameterFormDescriptor()Ljava/util/List;
```

I have an interface that defines the method as follows:

```
List<ParamFormElement> getParameterFormDescriptor();
```

And as I said this method is implemented by the implementing class.

The interface is included in a jar that is in my local Maven repository. I already tried `mvn clean` and `mvn install` and bumping the version number, but this does not solve the problem.

The implementing class is in another jar file which I create using an ANT-script. The file is then loaded via a ClassLoader in the main application.

Any clues why I get this error? All other methods defined by the interface are working.

**Here comes the code**

I have a Wicket `WebPage` where I make the call to this method:

```
public class AddJobPage extends BasePage {

    public AddJobPage(final PageParameters params) {
        super(params);

        final Workable w =
                WorkableManager.getInstance().findWorkableByName(params.get("workableName").toString());
        w.getParameterFormDescriptor();
    }

}
```

The `WorkableManager` internally loads the jar-file which includes the implementing class using an `URLClassLoader`. This is working fine and I get an instance
of the needed class.

The interface that defines the method is:

```
public interface Workable {

    List<ParamFormElement> getParameterFormDescriptor();

}
```

And the implementing class looks like this (`Module` extends `Workable`):

```
public class HTMLExport implements Module {

    @Override
    public final List<ParamFormElement> getParameterFormDescriptor() {
        final List<ParamFormElement> form = new ArrayList<>();
        form.add(new ParamFormElement(ParamFormElement.Type.TEXT, "Bitte eingeben:", "test"));
        return form;
    }

}
```

The interface is in a separate project and assembled as a jar-file in my local Maven repository. The `HTMLExport` class is in a different project, too and
compiled and assembled using Ant. The resulting jar-file is in a folder next to my main application and as I said loading the class works. The main application
is a Maven project and has the interface added as a dependency. In Eclipse I do not have any errors or warnings.

The stacktrace is following:

```
Root cause:

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: htmlexport.HTMLExport.getParameterFormDescriptor()Ljava/util/List;
    at web.pages.AddJobPage.<init>(AddJobPage.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:171)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:99)
    at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:137)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:268)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:166)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.isPageStateless(WebPageRenderer.java:300)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.shouldRenderPageAndWriteResponse(WebPageRenderer.java:342)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:837)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1631)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Complete stack:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public web.pages.AddJobPage(org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters)' and argument 'workableName=[HTML Export]'. An exception has been thrown during construction!
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:194)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:99)
    at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:137)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:268)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:166)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.isPageStateless(WebPageRenderer.java:300)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.shouldRenderPageAndWriteResponse(WebPageRenderer.java:342)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:837)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:171)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:99)
    at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:137)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:268)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:166)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.isPageStateless(WebPageRenderer.java:300)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.shouldRenderPageAndWriteResponse(WebPageRenderer.java:342)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:837)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
```

Comment: Show that code that throws this error.

Comment: And please show the full stack trace, whenever you ask a question in java the stack trace is the main thing that will help us help you.

Comment: is it your implementing class's jar is in the classpath?

Comment: Sorry guys, I will post the code tommorow. I have left the office for today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the implementing class was not compiled correctly and the Ant script did not copy the correct class into the jar-file. I converted it to a maven project and now the method can be found.

Comment: That's what is called incompatible jars. :) Good it's working for you now!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the latest jar file in your class path not a older copy. If you are seeing this at run time this happens due to incompatible binaries

From Oracle java site

> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; **this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled**.

[Link to Class AbstractMethodError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html)

Also try the -U flag forces to update dependencies.

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Comment: I have read this and I have also updated all jars, thus I am totally confused.

Answer (score 1):

if your implementing class's jar is not in the classpath or not sure

try like below code

```
    YourInterfaceName obj = (YourInterfaceName)Class.forName
("yourPackageName.YourInterfaceImplClassName").newInstance();
```

Comment: As I wrote, it is not in the initial classpath, but loaded by a custom ClassLoader.

Comment: No, because the class is loaded. I can access all other methods defined in the class. And the instantiation does work. Otherwise I would get another error, because the object can not be created.