# Why I receive an error when I use exposed in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jetbrains-ide, kotlin-exposed

I need to receive region_name by region_code from Oracle DB

I use [Exposed](http://%20https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) for my program, but I receive error

```
in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Transaction.closeExecutedStatements(Transaction.kt:181)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.inTopLevelTransaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:75)
```

Code is

```
object Codes : Table("REGIONS") {
val region_code = varchar("region_code",32)
val region_name = varchar("region_name",32)}
```

The main fun contains

```
.......
val conn = Database.connect("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//...", driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
    user = "...", password = "...")

transaction(java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED, 1, conn) {
        addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)
        Codes.select { Codes.region_code eq "a" }.limit(1).forEach {
            print(it[Codes.region_name])
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`AbstractMethodError` usually means that you compiled the code with one version of a library, but are running it against a different (incompatible) version.  (See for example [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137073/abstract-method-error) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656915/getting-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-on-implemented-method).)

So I'd check your dependencies &c carefully.

Comment: Thank you! It helps me! I used old jdbc driver for Oracle 12. I changed driver version to ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar