# javax ServletInputStream.isFinished() - abstractMethodError

Tags: solr, lucene, jetty, servlet-3.1

Trying to host solr 5.0 in jetty 8. [This line in solr codebase](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/servlet/SolrDispatchFilter.java#L330) (the `isFinished()` method) was throwing a `NoSuchMethodException` since I was using servlet API 3.0.

The error was replaced with `AbstractMethodException` when I upgraded to javax-servlet-api 3.1. The problem seems to be that `isFinished()` is indeed an abstract method, as [shown here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax/servlet/ServletInputStream.java#154)

The javax ServletRequest class does return an instance of the (abstract) ServletInputStream as [shown here](http://www.servlets.com/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream()) - and at least in my case the InputStream in jetty `ServletRequest.getInputStream()` seems to return a `ServletInputStream` with `isFinished()` not implemented, and hence the error.

Any work arounds? I must be missing something here since I do not think the [solr codebase](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/servlet/SolrDispatchFilter.java#L330) would be invoking an `HttpServletRequest.getInputStream().isFinished()` if it had not expected a properly instantiated ServletInputStream.

Answer (score 3):

> Note: [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html)

It is not possible to host Solr 5 (or anything that requires Servlet 3.1) in Jetty 8.

The first version of Jetty to support Servlet 3.1 was Jetty 9.1.

Comment: Ok thanks. That's what I needed to know. If I'm using servlet 3.1 then Jetty 9 is a must it seems

Comment: Why technically correct , the answer doesn't explicitly state that there is a mismatch between the newer interface and older implementation versions (see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969365/why-i-am-getting-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-errors )