# When add the Firebase in My app then it shows the Fatal Exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-5-thread-1
    Process: com.stemdot.chopesdriver, PID: 29923
      java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.handleIntent(android.content.Intent)"
          at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$1.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Are you using the same version for Firebase and Google play services?

Comment: Explantion of the exception here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17969365/4815718.  Post the dependencies block from your build.gradle file.  You may be using incompatible library versions.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You should keep google play service version the same as firebase messaging and firebase core version.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. I followed the FCM tutorial and got this exception. I fixed this error by changing the firebase-messaging lib to the latest version in the gradle file.

When I copied from the tutorial, it was:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

I changed it to the latest version as of now and everything works:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these three lines in gradle...

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
  compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1")
```