# Resolve Uncaught exception spotted in thread main: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, python, uncaught-exception

I am trying to call a java service from python. I am appending current timestamp to the file name to create a dynamic file name and passing it as a parameter in the java command. When I don't append the timestamp and pass the parameter as is, the code works but when I append the timestamp, I get **Uncaught exception spotted in thread main: java.lang.AbstractMethodError** error.

The code that doesn't works:

```
import subprocess
import time

Class DH:

    @staticmethod
    def restart_server(CLASSPATH, CLIENT_JVM_OPTIONS, SERVER_JVM_OPTIONS, SERVER_CONNECTION, DB_CONFIG, USER, SERVER_LOG, VERBOSE_OPTION):
        subprocess.call("java -cp " + CLASSPATH + " " + CLIENT_JVM_OPTIONS + " -Djava.security.policy=..\\conf\\rmi.policy lib/main/Run -s " + SERVER_CONNECTION + " -user " + USER + " " + VERBOSE_OPTION + " shutdown SERVER")
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d - %H%M%S")
        log_file_name = "..\logs\DHLogFile" + timestr + ".log"
        print(log_file_name)
        subprocess.call("java -cp " + CLASSPATH + " " + SERVER_JVM_OPTIONS + " -Djava.security.policy=..\conf\\rmi.policy lib/main/Server -export " + SERVER_CONNECTION + " -db " + DB_CONFIG + " -log " + log_file_name + " -loglevel EFWIT " + VERBOSE_OPTION)
```

The code that works,

```
import subprocess
import time

Class DH:

    @staticmethod
    def restart_server(CLASSPATH, CLIENT_JVM_OPTIONS, SERVER_JVM_OPTIONS, SERVER_CONNECTION, DB_CONFIG, USER, SERVER_LOG, VERBOSE_OPTION):
        subprocess.call("java -cp " + CLASSPATH + " " + CLIENT_JVM_OPTIONS + " -Djava.security.policy=..\\conf\\rmi.policy lib/main/Run -s " + SERVER_CONNECTION + " -user " + USER + " " + VERBOSE_OPTION + " shutdown SERVER")
        log_file_name = "..\logs\DHLogFile.log"
        subprocess.call("java -cp " + CLASSPATH + " " + SERVER_JVM_OPTIONS + " -Djava.security.policy=..\conf\\rmi.policy lib/main/Server -export " + SERVER_CONNECTION + " -db " + DB_CONFIG + " -log " + log_file_name + " -loglevel EFWIT " + VERBOSE_OPTION)
```

The full error is:

```
E 28/12/17-11:37:36.358 [-5]  Uncaught exception spotted in thread main: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
E 28/12/17-11:37:36.358 [-5]  java.lang.AbstractMethodError : 
lib.main.a$a.a([Ljava/lang/String;I)I
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: lib.main.a$a.a([Ljava/lang/String;I)I
    at lib.main.a.processArgs(SourceFile:646)
    at lib.main.a.setupEnv(SourceFile:1078)
    at lib.main.Server.main(SourceFile:157)
```

Could you please help me understand what is giving me AbstractMethodError Exception as I really want to have timestamp in the filename.

Comment: Can you paste full error log?

Comment: I don't really understand as I print the log_file_name it gets printed, then why does it throw an exception when I use that filename when calling the java service.

Comment: @Sundararaj Govindasamy I added the error, please take a look.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969365/why-i-am-getting-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-errors

Comment: No, I did take a look, its not related to this error.

Comment: If you could try to run the code and execute, that would be very much helpful.