# Error while running PySpark streaming using kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

Pyspark newbie.

Getting error when pyspark workers are executed.

Pyspark script:

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 pyspark-shell'

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSparkStreamingKafka_RM_01")
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)

kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 'localhost:2181', 'test', {'test':1})

parsed = kafkaStream.map(lambda v: v)
parsed.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

VERSIONS:

Using `kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1` and `Pyspark version 2.3.0` with `Python version 3.6.4` os `MacOs sierra`

Zookeeper command:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Kafka command:

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Loading some data to queue using

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test < /tmp/test_log.log
```

Verified that `test` queue indeed receiving data in queue by running below command (data was indeed loaded to test queue)

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
```

sample test_log.log data

```
2018-05-01 13:29:54,287 30337 log_generator.py 145 log-generator DEBUG (over headset)
2018-05-01 13:29:54,951 30337 log_generator.py 139 log-generator ERROR metallic surface begin to become visible. A large dish antenna
2018-05-01 13:29:55,876 30337 log_generator.py 143 log-generator WARNING worked with him before. Here he comes.
2018-05-01 13:29:56,196 30337 log_generator.py 139 log-generator ERROR (to Artoo)
```

Now when I run via spark-submit or python pysparkStreaming.py am getting

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]2018-05-01 19:43:50 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
:
:
:
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-05-01 19:43:50 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
2018-05-01 19:43:50 ERROR ReceiverTracker:91 - Receiver has been stopped. Try to restart it.
```

Complete log https://justpaste.it/522fy

Comment: you should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969365/why-i-am-getting-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-errors

Comment: @naren, Did you able to fix this issue? I have got into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a version incompatibility issue.

If you're using the latest spark version (2.3) check:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#creating-streaming-dataframes-and-streaming-datasets

`Kafka source - Reads data from Kafka. It’s compatible with Kafka broker versions 0.10.0 or higher. See the Kafka Integration Guide for more details.`

Comment: I did try 2.11 and got same results :(